# Server writes message to client only when Stream Writer Auto Flush given true. Can Anyone tel me Why?

Tags: tcp, streamwriter, autoflush

Here is my server side code that writes the data to client.

```
         try
         {
            IPHostEntry addr = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress localIP = 
             addr.AddressList.Where(x => 
            x.AddressFamily      ==AddressFamily.InterNetwork).FirstOrDefault();
            //Console.WriteLine(localIP);
            listener = new TcpListener(localIP,2055);
            listener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                s = listener.AcceptSocket();
                stream = new NetworkStream(s);
                strread = new StreamReader(stream);
                strwrite = new StreamWriter(stream);
                //strwrite.AutoFlush = true;
                strwrite.WriteLine("Hello");
                //    string recvmessage = strread.ReadLine();
                //    Console.WriteLine(recvmessage);
                //    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(recvmessage))
                //    strwrite.WriteLine("Idealist");
            }


        }
```

The Server side code writes data to client only when autoflush is given true.Can anyone please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it gets flushed automatically, of course. If you look at the Javadoc you'll see that autoflush happens when the data contains a newline. If you don't set this, the data doesn't get flushed until you call `flush()` yourself, or close the `OutputStream` or `Writer` yourself.